# Debezium SQL Server Connector Kafka Initial Snapshot

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

according to the Debezium SQL Server Connector documentation, initial snapshot only fires on connector first run.
However if I delete connector and **create new one but with the same name**, initial snapshot is not working also.
Is this by design or known Issue?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Connect stores details about connectors such as their snapshot status and ingest progress even after they've been deleted. If you recreate it with the same name it will assume it's the same connector and thus will try to continue from where the previous connector got to.

If you want a connector to start from scratch (i.e. run snapshot etc) then **you need to give the connector a new name**. (Technically, you could also go into Kafka Connect and muck about with the internal data to remove the data for the connector of the same name, but that's probably a bad idea)

Answer (score 1):

Give your connector a new database.server.name value or create a new topic. The reason why the snapshot doesn't fire again is because the current offset value for your topic and consumer has already passed the snapshot count index.